# How to download file mime_type:application/octet-stream using laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-storage

Using Storage

In older version of Laravel is working fine but Laravel9 is creating an issue

File Mime type: **application/octet-stream**

```
return Storage::download($shippingLabelPrn);
```

Laravel9 shows error
[image]

---

I research the file system and found one code

```
/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Local/FallbackMimeTypeDetector.php


class FallbackMimeTypeDetector implements MimeTypeDetector {

    private const INCONCLUSIVE_MIME_TYPES = [
        'application/x-empty',
        'text/plain',
        'text/x-asm',
        'application/octet-stream',
        'inode/x-empty',
    ];

    public function __construct(
            private MimeTypeDetector $detector,
            private array $inconclusiveMimetypes = self::INCONCLUSIVE_MIME_TYPES
    ) {}

    public function detectMimeTypeFromFile(string $path): ?string {
        $mimeType = $this->detector->detectMimeTypeFromFile($path);
        if ($mimeType !== null && !in_array($mimeType, $this->inconclusiveMimetypes)) { <-------this line ignore 
            return $mimeType;
        }
        return $this->detector->detectMimeTypeFromPath($path);
    }
}
```

Some mime types here are "INCONCLUSIVE_MIME_TYPES" which exclude.

So here the code extracts it even after getting the mimetype

So, how to download this type of mime files?

Comment: Please show us the code that _you_ wrote that actually raised this error, not an excerpt from a library file that you suspect _might_ contain the problem.

Comment: return Storage::download($shippingLabelPrn);
this is my code and the file mime type is "application/octet-stream". and the error mentioned in the above screenshot